# Numpy Array reshape: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 360 into shape (1,60,1)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I do have an np array that looks like that:

`[[-4.67069069e+02 -6.36386712e+00 -2.04863793e-02 -6.60781838e+00 -6.23597525e+00 -6.36389266e+00] [-4.67069069e+02 -6.36387170e+00 -2.04863796e-02 -6.60782580e+00 -6.23597425e+00 -6.36388226e+00]`

The length is 60.

My code is the following now:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
...
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
...
window_size = 60
last_sequence = val_data[-window_size:]
last_sequence = scaler.transform(last_sequence)
last_sequence = last_sequence.reshape((1, window_size, 1))
```

The error message:

last_sequence = last_sequence.reshape((1, window_size, 1))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 360 into shape (1,60,1)

What do I do wrong?

I tried already to create a new numpy array, it dit not work.

Comment: Your program has invalid syntax. The array should be `[[-4.67069069e+02 -6.36386712e+00 -2.04863793e-02 -6.60781838e+00 -6.23597525e+00 -6.36389266e+00] , [-4.67069069e+02 -6.36387170e+00 -2.04863796e-02 -6.60782580e+00 -6.23597425e+00 -6.36388226e+00]]`. Moreover, the length of the array you provide is nowhere 60 and what is `val_data` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is somewhat self-explaining, but I gave you some comments and a work around that may or may not fit to your use-case

```
window_size = 60

# `last_sequence` will have size 60 in the first dimension, other dimensions can be different
last_sequence = val_data[-window_size:]

# check the size of all dimensions
print(last_sequence.shape)  # notice that the shape is (60, other_dim, ...)

last_sequence = scaler.transform(last_sequence)  # the dimension will still be 60 in first dim, but there are other dimensions of your data

# this line wont work as you cannot squeeze 360 values in a array that has only 60 entries

last_sequence = last_sequence.reshape((1, window_size, 1))

# you could do this instead:
last_sequence = last_sequence.reshape((1, window_size, -1))  # passing `-1` will cause this dimension to be automatically of the necessary size to fit to the data. If this is what you want depends on your application
```